# Haskell file reading and finding values

Tags: file, haskell, multiple-columns, rows

I have recently started learning Haskell and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to interpret text files.

I have following .txt file:

```
ncols         5
nrows         5
xllcorner     809970
yllcorner     169790
cellsize      20
NODATA_value  -9999
9 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 2 0 0 3
```

The first 6 lines just display some information I need when working with the file in a GIS software. The real deal starts when I try to work with the numbers below in Haskell.

I want to tell Haskell to look up where the numbers 9, 1, 2 and 3 are and print back the number of the row and column where those numbers actually are. In this case Haskell should print:

```
The value 9 is in row 1 and column 1
The value 1 is in row 2 and column 2
The value 2 is in row 5 and column 2
The value 3 is in row 5 and column 5
```

I tried finding the solution (or at least similar methods for interpreting files) in tutorials and other Haskell scripts without any success, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of a script to do what you want. Note that this will in its current form does not fail gracefully (but given this is a script, I doubt this is a concern). Make sure there is a trailing newline at the end of your file!

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM, when)
import Data.Traversable (for)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main = do

  -- numbers we are looking for
  numbers <- getArgs 

  -- get the key-value metadata
  metadata <- replicateM 6 $ do
    [key,value] <- words <$> getLine
    return (key,value)

  let Just rows = read <$> lookup "nrows" metadata
      Just cols = read <$> lookup "ncols" metadata

  -- loop over all the entries
  for [1..rows] $ \row ->do
    rawRow <- words <$> getLine
    for (zip [1..cols] rawRow) $ \(col,cell) ->
      when (cell `elem` numbers)
        (putStrLn ("The value " ++ cell ++ " is in row " ++ show row ++ " and column " ++ show col))
```

To use it, pass it as command line arguments the numbers you are looking for and then feed as input your data file.

```
$ ghc script.hs
$ ./script 9 1 2 3 < data.txt
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

---

I wasn't really sure if you wanted to look up just a fixed set of numbers, or any non-zero number. As your question asked for the former, that is what I did.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a lifesaver! One more question though, where exactly should I feed my data and the numbers? If I use for example: data <- getData "test.txt", it just throws an error back.

Comment: Added some description. The file is expected as standard input, so some shell commands can save the day.

Comment: Again, thank you very much. This really helped me a lot! Last question: is there any way to do this automatically after compiling the script in GHCi? Cheers!

Comment: @EvilHappyHippo in GHCi it might be a bit annoying - I really recommend you just compile it with GHC and then run it. The problem is that I know of no easy way to redirect input from a file for GHCi.